# Continuous Random Variable- Exponential distribution

Tags: probability

Commonly, car cooling systems are controlled by electrically driven fans. Assuming that the lifetime T in hours of a particular make of fan can be modeled by an exponential distribution with $\lambda=.0003$. Find the proportion that give at least 10,000 hours service.

$\int_{10,000}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

$-e^{-\lambda x} \Big\vert_{10,000}^{\infty}= -e^{-\infty}- -.049787 = 4.97687 \%$

Then finally, would you expect more fans or less fans if it were remodeled at $\lambda=.00035$? Is the work to my first problem correct?

Comment: `.049787=4.97687` ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the probability of an exponential RV with parameter $\lambda$ 
having a value greater than some $s$ is $$\exp{(-\lambda s)}$$.

As for the second part of your question, it is quite clear that if $\lambda$
is increased, the event that the lifetime is greater than $s$ becomes further less probable.